# Ramda, send args in function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ramda.js

```
const product = {
  name: 'widget',
  price: 10,
  avgRating: 4.5,
  shippingWeight: '2 lbs',
  shippingCost: 2,
  shippingMethod: 'UPS'
}

const getProps = R.pick(['name', 'price'])
const result = getProps(product) // {name: 'widget', price: 10}
```

In my `getProps` I would like to send the keys ( name and price) dynamically.

Something like

```
const getProps = args => R.pick([..args]);
const result = getProps(['name', 'price'], product);
```

Doesn't work.

How should I do this?

https://plnkr.co/edit/MHv5AMEO3p9dxiNCvQ80?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your pick you did not pass the object properly ([as per the R.pick documentation](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#pick)).

You can either do it like this:

```js
const product = {
  name: 'widget',
  price: 10,
  avgRating: 4.5,
  shippingWeight: '2 lbs',
  shippingCost: 2,
  shippingMethod: 'UPS'
}

const getProps = (obj, propsArr) => R.pick(obj, propsArr)

console.log(getProps(['name','price'], product))
console.log(getProps(['avgRating','shippingMethod'], product))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Or you could destructure the passed parameters like this:

```js
const product = {
  name: 'widget',
  price: 10,
  avgRating: 4.5,
  shippingWeight: '2 lbs',
  shippingCost: 2,
  shippingMethod: 'UPS'
}

const getProps = (...args) => R.pick(...args)

console.log(getProps(['name','price'], product))
console.log(getProps(['shippingCost','shippingMethod'], product))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: So when you only have the main object, you don't have to name it in the getProps function (R.pick only has 1 argument in my example), but if you have two, you have to also name the main object in the ramda function?

Comment: Good question. I missed that this was your intent. Updated the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Your 1st answer can be replaced with R.flip(R.pick). The 2nd one is totally redundant - get the parameters, and then apply them in the same order.

Answer (score 0):

Ramda methods are curried, which means that whenever the number of arguments is less than the arity (the number of parameters the function expects), a new function is returned. So if a function excepts fn(a, b, c), when curried you can do `fna = fn(a)`, `fnab = fna(b)`, etc...

Unlike classic currying, in ramda you can also pass multiple arguments - `fnab = fn(a, b)`.

What you want is already the standard way in which `R.pick` works. It can be called with a single argument, and return a function that expects the other one, or you can call it with the all the arguments at once, and get the result.

```js
const product = {
  name: 'widget',
  price: 10,
  avgRating: 4.5,
  shippingWeight: '2 lbs',
  shippingCost: 2,
  shippingMethod: 'UPS'
}

const getProps = R.pick

console.log(getProps(['name','price'], product))
console.log(getProps(['shippingCost','shippingMethod'], product))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```